# How to deal with browser cache while using browserSync?

Tags: gulp, browser-cache, browser-sync

I'm using gulp with browserSync with next config(simplified):

```
gulp.task('serve', ['compile_styles'], function() {
    browserSync.init({
        proxy: 'my-local-dev.site'
    });

    gulp.watch('/public/styles/**/*.scss', ['compile_styles']);
    gulp.watch('/public/js/**/*.js').on('change', browserSync.reload);
    gulp.watch('/**/*.php').on('change', browserSync.reload);
});
```

SCSS changes being pushed through `.pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}))` inside `compile_styles` task, but as you can see for `.js` files I used simple `browserSync.reload` and it is not working because browser(*chrome 57.0.2987.133 (64-bit)*) loads static files from it's internal cache so I need to make additional reload to flush that cache and force browser to load that files again.

The same thing can be related to any static resources such as images, fonts and etc. **So how to deal with browser cache while using browserSync?**

Comment: Why don't you add {stream: true} to your js watcher browserSync.reload call?  I do not have to do an additional reload beyond that called in gulp.  Your image files should be able to be reinjected into the page without a reload/refresh at all.

Comment: @Mark hmmm... thanks for the idea, I have rewritten my config a little bit and it seems to be work properly right now. I'll post the answer shortly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found a solution through using `{stream: true}` parameter of `browserSync.reload` function, but to make it work, some changes required. So how it was:

```
gulp.watch('/public/js/**/*.js').on('change', browserSync.reload);
```

and how it looks now:

```
gulp.watch('/public/js/**/*.js').on('change', function(e) {
    return gulp.src(e.path)
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}));
});
```

Comment: thx for your question & your answer. My problem is not completely solved. Injection works fine, but when I reload a page or move to another page: Chrome (57) still renders using an old stylesheet. A **hard reload** solves this. I am also considering to give the stylesheets a random string / timestamp to trick Chrome to actually load the thing.

Comment: @FrankLämmer same here, did you manage to solve this? My solution was to change the proxy port to something else. It works, however, I'll need to choose a new proxy port for each project until I find something else.

Comment: @Gus sorry no (not soo important here right now). I consider "HTTP cache-control"/ETag might play a role here. maybe [not](https://github.com/browsersync/browser-sync/issues/657).

Comment: @FrankLämmer @Gus check out AbdelhakAj's answer with `gulp-cache` plugin, probably solves the issue.

Answer (score 7):

why don't you use gulp-cache

```
var cache = require('gulp-cache');   

gulp.task('clearCache', function() {

  // Still pass the files to clear cache for
  gulp.src('./lib/*.js')
  .pipe(cache.clear());

  // Or, just call this for everything
  cache.clearAll();

});
```

and then add this task to your watcher

Comment: In case there are any other gulp noobs like me who run across this: (1) I had to install gulp-cache version < 1.0 to use this importing method. (2) the "add this task to your watcher" means the second part of the watcher is a list of actions to perform, like this: `gulp.watch(['./**/*.{scss,css,html,py,js}'], ['clearCache', reload]);`

Answer (score 5):

In chrome devtools (CTRL MAJ I), in *Network* tab, you have a *Disable cache* checkbox. It should work.

Comment: As I know, this setting works only when devtools is open, so it does not completely solve an issue.

Answer (score 1):

This solved my problem:

1- Install gulp-cache npm package

`npm i gulp-cache`

2-Require this package in your gulpfile.js by adding the following line:

`const cache = require('gulp-cache');`

3- Now you want to create a gulp task that clear the cache using gulp-cache:

```
function clearCache(done) {
  return cache.clearAll(done);
}
```

4- Finally update your watch task, I'll share mine as a reference:

```
function watch() {
  browserSync.init({
    server: './dist',
  });
  gulp.watch('sass/**/*.scss', gulp.parallel(styles));
  gulp.watch('sass/**/*.scss').on('change', clearCache, browserSync.reload);
  gulp.watch('index.html', gulp.parallel(copyHtml));
  gulp.watch('*.html').on('change', browserSync.reload);
  gulp.watch('js/**/*.js', gulp.series(lint, scripts));
  gulp.watch('js/**/*.js').on('change', clearCache, browserSync.reload);
  gulp.watch('img/**/*.jpg', gulp.series(copyImages));
  gulp.watch('img/**/*').on('change', clearCache, browserSync.reload);
}
```

If you look closely you'll notice I change each of my gulp.watch by adding clear cache to the list of function to run after change:

```
gulp.watch('sass/**/*.scss', gulp.parallel(styles));
gulp.watch('sass/**/*.scss').on('change', clearCache, browserSync.reload);
```

Please let me know if this works for you!